# How to change the time format of Darksky API request?

Tags: javascript, php, api

I use Darksky API to get the information of weather in Yii 2.0.

Here is how to send a request to Darksky,

```
https://api.darksky.net/forecast/[key]/[latitude],[longitude],[time]
```

When I use a variable `time` in UNIX time(for example `1540407992`), it works well. 
But I want to use `time` in date format `YYYY-mm-dd H:i:s`(for example`2018-10-24 19:06:32`) without converting it into UNIX time.

Is it possible? Please, give me correct answer.

Comment: If the API requires Unix then no, it's not possible. But you can use strtotime to convert a date to unix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the API docs, it is possible:

> time required Either be a UNIX time (that is, seconds since midnight
>   GMT on 1 Jan 1970) or a string formatted as follows:
>   [YYYY]-[MM]-[DD]T[HH]:[MM]:[SS][timezone]. timezone should either be
>   omitted (to refer to local time for the location being requested), Z
>   (referring to GMT time), or +[HH][MM] or -[HH][MM] for an offset from
>   GMT in hours and minutes. The timezone is only used for determining
>   the time of the request; the response will always be relative to the
>   local time zone.

So the format you need is `[YYYY]-[MM]-[DD]T[HH]:[MM]:[SS]`, for your example `2018-10-24 19:06:32` becomes `2018-10-24T19:06:32` with an optional timezone.

Comment: Thanks. but how to use timezone for GMT+3? 2018-10-24T19:06:32Z+3 or 2018-10-24T19:06:32+[03][00]? I am not clear.

Comment: `2018-10-24T19:06:32Z+3` or `2018-10-24T19:06:32Z+0300`. Try sending the requests and see what works.

Answer (score 0):

I used this in my app and read the docs for Darksky api as mentioned in posts above and the docs for Angular DatePipe https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe. Just thought I would share a method I used.
`<h5>{{ day.time * 1000 | date: 'fullDate' }}</h5>`
And this displays the full date for example Monday August 17, 2020.